# Rails fixtures use empty_clob() with CLOB fields but nothing else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, rails-activerecord

I'm back with Rails fixtures after seeing they were much improved since the last time I used them.

```
#models.yml
one:
  id: 1
  clob_field: "My Text"
```

When the models fixture is loaded into the DB - I can see that the clob text (My Text) is substituted with an empty_clob() call (in the `insert` statement)

According to my understanding, the Oracle enhanced adapter should make another update statement that sets the `clob_field` appropriately - but this doesn't get executed (and the value remains blank).

Any idea why that is?

Comment: Interesting that someone decided to downvote the question without giving a clue why. Is it because of 'fixtures', my lack of understanding of something, my setting of 'id' (which's got it's reasons), or what?

Answer (score 1):

I traced the fixture loading and found out that that was due to a mixture of specifying a schema_name along with the table_name (`self.table_name = "SCHEMA_OWNER.TABLE_NAME"`) as well as using upper-case TABLE_NAMES.

I've worked-around the issue by overriding `insert_fixture` method (in the oracle-enhanced adapter) to properly manipulate `table_name`.

Now the `write_lobs` is being called correctly.

#### UPDATE

Here's the change as requested by @jeff-k

# config/initializers/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb

```
  ...
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedAdapter.class_eval do


    # Overriding this method to account for including the schema_name in the table name
    # which is implemented to work around another limitation of having the schema_owner different
    # than the connected user
    #
    # Inserts the given fixture into the table. Overridden to properly handle lobs.
    def insert_fixture(fixture, table_name) #:nodoc:
      super

      if table_name =~ /\./i
        table_name = table_name.downcase.split('.')[1]
      end

      if ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names
        klass = table_name.to_s.singularize.camelize
      else
        klass = table_name.to_s.camelize
      end

      klass = klass.constantize rescue nil
      if klass.respond_to?(:ancestors) && klass.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)
        write_lobs(table_name, klass, fixture, klass.lob_columns)
      end
    end
  end
end
```